# Adjust Volume in-App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, audio, volume

How can I adjust the iphone volume in my app? There is a way (pandora does it) but I just don't know how to.

I mainly need to be able to set the volume to max, and then set it to nothing later.

Does anyone have any ideas or tutorials?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm gonna be so unhappy when the volume suddenly goes to max. I like to control my own devices. However, your idea has been very popular on TV -- they like to up the volume for commercials. And look how much we like that.

Comment: Here is a blogpost of someone who claims to have found a way to do this (I haven't tried it): http://blog.stormyprods.com/2009/06/adjusting-iphone-master-volume.html . That said, the feature they use is an undocumented one so use at your own risk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to allow the user to control the volume while in your app, which is what Pandora is doing, you're looking for [MPVolumeView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Having used the same control myself, I'm 90% sure that is what Pandora is using.

Comment: Thanks, but do you know if there is a way to set the volume without the slider?

Comment: I would be willing to bet that Apple doesn't provide a way to do that, for the reasons brought up in the comments for your original post.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a way to do this for my MPMoviePlayerController, and after DAYS of searching, turns out it's just one line.

`[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:(use a value between 0.0 and 1.0)]`

The catch being that your `MPMoviePlayerController` needs to be using the application audio session.

Note that from my testing this works ONLY for MPMoviePlayerController - I cannot be certain about the effect this has on AVAudioPlayers etc. But it's worth a shot anyway.

Edit: Oh, also. It seems kinda hacky - although it all boils down to how each component interacts with the application audio session, I'm not ACTIVELY setting any property of that sort on the `applicationMusicPlayer`. That setting the volume property on it also influences my MPMoviePlayerController is a lucky accident, and there really is no way to be sure this behavior won't change in a future release! /Disclaimer.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is deprecated in iOS 7. I don't think there's an alternative, apart from MPVolumeView, but that doesn't allow you to change the volume programmatically I believe. It requires user interaction. Correct me if I'm wrong.